# Xcode: Parse.com query that requires a particular key's array contains every AND ONLY the elements of the provided array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

In parse.com I have a Messages class and the objects in that class have a column named "recipientIds". The recipientIds key contains an array of users for each object. I want to query only the objects whose recipientIds array contain the exact same array items as the provided array (no more, no less)

I tried both of the following

```
[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" containedIn:myFriendsArray];
[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" containsAllObjectsInArray:myFriendsArray];
```

but these didn't work because they both returned additional objects that contained additional recipients. Is there a different way to arrange my query so that I only receive the objects with the exact same recipients as myFriendsArray.  I basically need a method that containsAll**AndOnly**ObjectsInArray.

Comment: Have you tried `[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:myFriendsArray];`?

Comment: Kyle, that doesn't work either. It returns results that just have one matching its too, not every and only.